# Currently geckodriver for freebsd with python 3.7 (firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I got problem with set up in my freebsd selenium with geckodriver.
im getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skriptas.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver = Firefox(executable_path=path, options=options)
  File "/home/m=MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/MyUserName/skriptas/forGeckodriver/geckodriver'
```

I read alot about it and found what error `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:` means  probably installed a version of geckodriver that is meant for a different OS/platform.

I try install from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

- geckodriver-v0.28.0-linux32.tar.gz
- geckodriver-v0.28.0-linux64.tar.gz

My code in python

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expected
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import logging

FORMAT = "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)


path='/home/MyUserName/skriptas/forGeckodriver/geckodriver'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = Firefox(executable_path=path, options=options)



driver.get("https://www.verivox.de/stromvergleich/vergleich/#/?plz=10555&persons=on&usage=3500&bonus=OnlyCompliant&profile=H0&product=electricity&source=1&q=WzYsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMiwyMCwwLDEsNzQxMTIyLCI3MTA4NSIsMSwyNDAsMjQwLDM1MDAsMCwwLDAsOTk5LC0xLC0xLC0xLDAsMCwiVG90YWxDb3N0cyIsIkFzY2VuZGluZyIsIk5vbmUiLDM4LCJBbm51YWxDb3N0VmlldyIsMF0%3D&partnerid=1")



allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))
for header in allheader:
     print("Header: " + header.text)
```

Please help me, all help will be appreciated.
If i wrong and error not because wrong version please write fix in answers.

Comment: What happens if you execute geckodriver binary from command line? Extract the downloaded tar file and try to run the binary with `geckodriver --version`. What is the output? Also, are you sure you have latest version of Firefox installed?

Comment: my firefox version is Mozilla Firefox 83.0, ```geckodriver --version``` output 
```geckodriver: Command not found```.  I put only file from here to my freebsd server and direct the path for it.

Comment: After you extract the tar file, run the geckodriver with the whole path: `/home/MyUserName/skriptas/forGeckodriver/geckodriver --version` .  What is the output?

Comment: version right now 0.26 and finally working,  was 0.28. Thank you for try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

i downdload geckodriver from [here](https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/quarterly/All/geckodriver-0.26.0_9.txz)
then say you dont have permision, so i write

```
chmod +x /home/MyUserName/skriptas/forGeckodriver/geckodriver
```

and now working. I think problem was with version, maybe freebsd not working with geckodriver-v0.28.0 version